# Generating Coherent Noise for the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: perlin-noise, noise

I've been doing research on game development in a hyperbolic plane, and cannot seem to find any solution for generating coherent noise.

Generating noise for a spherical geometry would be easy -- just generate 3D noise and sample it on the surface of a sphere.

But it does not seem to be the case that this technique works for sampling 3D noise on the surface of a hyperboloid.

It generates samples but those samples will get stretched out the further away they are from the origin.

Is there a technique for generating coherent noise that is similar across the hyperbolic plane?

I have considered that I could do a hyperbolic variation of [Worley noise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worley_noise) by hashing the position of a, say, [{4, 5} tiling cell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-5_square_tiling) to generate some random points in that cell. However, it would be ideal to have something closer to [Perlin noise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) as it has a nicer texture and can be sampled more arbitrarily.

Comment: If all else fails, I'll write a hyperbolic implementation of Worley and answer my own question for future readers.

Comment: Can you address the [{3,7} order-7 triangular tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-7_triangular_tiling) in such a way that you can find the containing triangle of a given input point, hashable vertex coordinates, vector offsets to, and the squared Euclidean distances to the vertices? That should be all you need for hyperbolic 2D Simplex noise.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can find a practical formula for an isometric embedding of 2D hyperbolic space into higher-dimensional Euclidean space like, say, the 6D that this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497883/which-of-the-non-euclidean-planes-can-we-embed-into-non-euclidean-3-space/497907#497907 indicates is possible, then you may be able to use an ordinary 6D noise function.

Comment: @KdotJPG A 6D noise function, now that just sounds delightful! I'll do some research into that. I'll self-answer with my findings one way or another. Rough thing is, Simplex Noise is in O(n^2) where n is the dimension, and apparently gets worse in appearance the higher the dimension as well. I appreciate your comments. "Isometric embedding" as opposed to simply "embedding" is not a term I'd come across yet.

Comment: @TimMorris I can confirm that the [appearance washes out as the dimensionality increases](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/4212/5349), at least with any implementation I've encountered.

Comment: @Pikalek That's a shame. I'd still love to mess around with H2 in E6 if there are practical equations to do so, it sounds neat. I created a question on Math SE for it.

Comment: If you can identify the {4, 5} tiling cell containing a point, the coordinates of that cell's vertices, and an interpolation weight between them, then you should be able to implement classic Perlin noise on those squares. The tricky part might be ensuring your gradient vectors are uniformly distributed. But I'd agree with KdotJPG that Simplex noise would be a better choice if the {3, 7} tiling is comparable work to use.

Comment: @DMGregory I'll give it a shot. I hope this question can be left open until I can post my experience with it.

Comment: @KdotJPG for what it's worth, that proof of H2 -> E6 turns out to be very implicit and there's no (known) usable mapping function between them. Sad that's a dead end because it would have been cool.

Comment: That's a shame. A further thought of mine might be to take the Order-5 or Order-6 square tiling and try assigning each vertex an integer lattice point in 6D (or higher!) such that all squares map to squares. You could also try the Order-7 triangular tiling by similar logic. Then look for (perhaps trigonometrically-based) functions that work on each patch to smooth the borders.